# How to list date of every monday and thrusdays in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, date, unix, scripting

If I give month and year as input the output should be dates of mondays and thrusdays of that month.

eg: If input is
year = 2013
month = 02
output should be

```
2013-02-04 
2013-02-07 
2013-02-11 
2013-02-14
2013-02-18
2013-02-21 
2013-02-25
2013-02-28
```

how to use date  function for this in shell scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method requires only 2 call to `date`, the rest is just arithmetic

```
year=2013
month=2
last=$(date -d "$year-$month-1 + 1 month - 1 day" +%d)
wday=$(date -d "$year-$month-1" +%w)
for (( day=1; day<=$last; day++ )); do
    if (( wday == 1 || wday == 4 )); then
        printf "%4d-%02d-%02d\n" $year $month $day
    fi
    (( wday = (wday + 1) % 7 ))
done
```

```
2013-02-04
2013-02-07
2013-02-11
2013-02-14
2013-02-18
2013-02-21
2013-02-25
2013-02-28
```

Answer (score 1):

```
year=2013
month=02

#Monday=1,Sunday=7
display_days="1 4"

for day in $(seq 1 31)
do
    dow=$(date -d "$year-$month-$day" +%u 2>/dev/null)
    for d in $display_days
    do
            if [ -z $dow ]; then continue; fi
            if [ "$dow" -eq "$d" ]
            then
                    date -d "$year-$month-$day" +%y-%m-%d
            fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just defer to `ncal`.

```
LC_ALL=C ncal "$@" | sed -n 's/\(Mo\|Th\)//p'
```

Weekdays are subject to localization so I added a C locale just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
year=2013 month=02
cal $month $year |  
sed '1,2d; s/^.. \(..\) .. .. \(..\).*/\1\n\2/' | 
sed "/^ *$/d; s/^ /0/; s/^/$year-$month-/"
```